# How to create vm using custom image from different storage account, on Azure

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager

I'm currently using [this template](https://github.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates/tree/master/101-vm-from-user-image) to create a vm by custom image. For the OS Disk part:

```
"storageProfile": {
  "osDisk": {
    "name": "[concat(variables('vmName'),'-osDisk')]",
    "osType": "[parameters('osType')]",
    "caching": "ReadWrite",
    "createOption": "FromImage",
    "image": {
      "uri": "[variables('userImageName')]"
    },
    "vhd": {
      "uri": "[variables('osDiskVhdName')]"
    }
  }
}
```

Is it possible that image and vhd field stored in different storage account?

### Update

I try to use two storage account in the same resource group. But the error message still mentions that "source and destination storage accounts are different"

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Here is what I found from launching VM from Azure ARM custom image through my test:

1. The custom image can be in different storage account other than the VM
2. The custom image storage account need to be within same subscription, same region and same resource group as the VM

I tried launching VM from custom image from different resource group and storage account(same subscription, same region) and got error:
"Source and destination storage accounts for disk are different"
But if I launch VM from custom image from different storage account while resource group is the same, I get my VM launched without error.

Comment: no, storage account that is holding the custom image, can exist in different resource group than storage account holding the vm that is to be created from image. but the error you are mentioning (related to different storage accounts) can be due to different storage account for 'VM VHD'. it should be same as custom image's

Answer (score 2):

It is a requirement that the source image and the destination vhd reside in the same storage account, however it is *not* required that the storage account be in the same resource group as the VM.  It must be in the same region/location, but does not have to be in the same resource group.

So you can set up a storage account beforehand, put your source image in there and not have to worry about copying it during deployment, that will happen automatically.  Here's a snippet of how I configure my templates:

```
"userImageName":"[concat('http://',parameters('userImageStorageAccountName'),'.blob.core.windows.net/',parameters('userImageStorageContainerName'),'/',parameters('userImageVhdName'))]",
"osDiskVhdContainer": "[concat('http://',parameters('userImageStorageAccountName'),'.blob.core.windows.net/',parameters('vmImageStorageContainerName'),'/')]"
```

Same storage account but different containers for images and vhds.

So make sure:

1. source and dest are in the same storageAccount
2. VM and storage are in the same region (e.g. East Asia)
3. use a new storage account (provisioned by ARM) not "classic"

Comment: I am using the template from here - https://github.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates/blob/master/101-vm-from-user-image/azuredeploy.json  I am not able to understand where shall I make the change so that the image vhd and vhd after spinning the vm resides in different container but in same storage account. Request you to guide me on this.

Comment: That particular template is should work ok as is... it expects you to provide the full uri of the source image, so something like: http://test.blob.core.windows.net/myimages/source.vhd - then the template will copy that image to a container named "vhds" - so as long as your source image is in a container *not* named "vhds" you're ok.  Note that you actually can have them in the same container as long as the filename is different, but I find that confusing to manager.  Does that help?

Comment: It helps. Thankyou :)

Answer (score 1):

For me it has just worked like this:

> Prerequisite - The Storage Account with the User Image VHD should BE
>   THE SAME, in the SAME GROUP.

Then, it worked.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how other answers are upvoted. OP post is correct - custom image and VM os disk needs to be in the same storage account which is a great limitation. Just tried that using the API and I'm getting:

```
"MsRestAzure::AzureOperationError: ConflictingUserInput: Source and destination storage accounts for disk test-terminate are different."
```

Answer (score 0):

If by `different storage account` you mean a storage account in another subscription, then no. The storage account and virtual machine must be in the same subscription.

**UPDATE**

Found the answer in the template description page here: https://github.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates/tree/master/101-vm-from-user-image

> Prerequisite - The Storage Account with the User Image VHD should
>   already exist in the same resource group.

So based on this, as long as your storage accounts are in same Azure Subscriptions and are in same Resource Group, you should be fine even if the storage accounts are different.

Comment: Hi, sorry for the misleading. I mean two storage account in in the same subscription.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. In the classic VM creation scenario, the storage accounts and VM should be in same subscriptions. For decreased latency, they should be in the same region (or "now deprecated" affinity group). Given that you are using Azure Resource Manager, I think in general same rule about same subscription and region would still apply but one thing needs to be checked is if they need to be in same Resource Group. Let me find out that information. Based on what I find, I will update my answer accordingly.

Comment: Updated my answer. HTH.

Comment: Thanks. My current work around is to create the storage account first and upload my image. Then use this template to create the VM. But it need 2 template to do so ( one for storage account , another for vm).

Comment: i'll try it again. If it doesn't work, i'll post the error message. Thank you for the support!

Comment: Just updated the result of the experiment. It still doesn't work~

Comment: Looks like I was wrong. Sorry about that. One thing you could do is copy the VHD from one storage account to another and proceed from there. Since the copy is performed on the server side, you don't have to download the VHD and reupload it. Will this work for you?

Comment: Ya, it's the way i'm doing now. But what i hope is that my template can contains the copy image part. Maybe i should embed a script to do so. Thanks for the support!