# Azure CLI creates VM from image in different region

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine, azure-cli

I have an image that I created in Azure that located in eastus. I want to deploy VM from that image in a different region (westeurope). I tried this CLI command but nothing is happening.

```
az vm create --resource-group Automationsystem --name VMEurope --location westeurope --image MyCustomImage --admin-username azureuser --size Standard_F4S --no-wait --ssh-key-value ~/mykey.pub
```

Is the option to deploy VM from image at another region exists?

Comment: [This article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32217720/how-to-create-vm-using-custom-image-from-different-storage-account-on-azure) suggests that you must have the image in the same region as VM.

Comment: @LechMigdal Thank you for your comment. So basically i need to create a new image at the region I want to deploy my VMs?

Comment: @liorko Yes, you need create a new image on westeurope or copy your image to the location.

Comment: @Liorko Unfortunately yes

Comment: @Walter-MSFT Thank you for your comment. Is there a simple command in the azure cli that copy my image?

Comment: @liorko Now, image does not support copy to other location.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Lech Migdal said, you must have the image in the same region as VM.

For now, image does not support copy to other location. You need create a new image on westeurope location. Please refer to the following steps.

1.Use the image to create a VM in the current location.

2.Create a storage account in westeurope.

3.Stop VM and copy VM's managed disk to new storage account.

```
$sas = Grant-AzureRmDiskAccess -ResourceGroupName "[ResourceGroupName]" -DiskName "[ManagedDiskName]" -DurationInSecond 3600 -Access Read  
$destContext = New-AzureStorageContext –StorageAccountName "[StorageAccountName]" -StorageAccountKey "[StorageAccountAccessKey]"
$blobcopy=Start-AzureStorageBlobCopy -AbsoluteUri $sas.AccessSAS -DestContainer "[ContainerName]" -DestContext $destContext -DestBlob "[NameOfVhdFileToBeCreated].vhd"
```

Note: Use image to create VM, the OS disk is managed disk.

4.Use the VHD to create a new VM, you could use the [template](https://github.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates/tree/master/201-vm-specialized-vhd-existing-vnet) to do this.

5.Use the VM to create a new image. Please refer to this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/linux/tutorial-custom-images).

Comment: @liorko If you have the image's original VHD, you could copy it to westeurope storage account directly and use the VHD to create a new VM, then create a new image.

Comment: 2022 November update: These days Azure allows you to share an image across multiple regions by means of "Azure compute galleries". You add your image into the gallery and then inside the gallery you use "Update replication" to replicate (basically to copy) your image into all the desired target regions. Now your image is available everywhere you choose.