# How to use Azure VM Image in different regions

Tags: azure, image, virtual-machine

I created Azure Image Galery and Image definition inside it in order to control versioning of my VMs. It is possible to use those images across different subscriptions, but I found that it is impossible to use it in different regions from where the definition was created.

Are there any ways to use the same image in multiple regions or is it required to separately replicate the image across multiple regions?

My current process is: Create new version of the image (manual process) and let terraform code update VM Scale Set.

Now when I need to support multiple regions, do I need to manually create those images everywhere?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use [Azure Compute Gallery](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/azure-compute-gallery) to share your images across multiple regions. You can add your image into the gallery and then use Update replication to copy your image into all the desired target regions. This way, you don’t need to manually create those [images everywhere](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/image-version?tabs=portal%2Ccli2).

Here is [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45671863/azure-cli-creates-vm-from-image-in-different-region) that can help.

Comment: Thank you!
Update replication is exactly what I was looking for